# Ubuntu 16.04 login loop, unity-panel-service-lockscreen fails

Tags: 16.04, unity, login-screen

After installing several updates and restarting Ubuntu 16.04, I was greeted with a strange looking login screen. When I try to login the same screen temporarily disappears and then reappears.

~/.xsession-errors shows:

upstart: Failed to spawn unity-panel-service-lockscreen pre-start process: unable to execute: No such file or directory

...

upstart: unity-panel-service main process (9326) killed ky HUP signal

and some other errors.

I can't find anything on Google about this error. Any suggestions?